# data load twice... means AsyncTask onPostExecute load same data twice?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

data load twice... means AsyncTask onPostExecute load same data twice?
my **AsyncTask onPostExecute** run twice it load same data... 
I am running async task to load results from a server. to show the data in gridview but the data show twice time..I am confused on why the AsyncTask outputs the data twice.
**Please Help me**
Here is my code:

```
public class InfoAccountsascyn extends AsyncTask <String, String, String>{

    String result;
    String s;
    private Activity activity;
    private String url;
    private String user_id;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONObject json;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "Success";
    int Success;

    public InfoAccountsascyn(Activity activity, String url,String user_id) {
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
        this.url = url;
        this.user_id=user_id;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Items...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        try {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("customer_id", user_id));
            //if(Last_id!=null){
            // params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("last_product_id", Last_id));
            // }

            json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);

            Success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (Success == 1) {
            result = json.toString();
        }else{
            try {
                result = json.getString("CartData");
                //s=result;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ((DetaildAddress) activity).parseJsonResponse(result);
        pDialog.dismiss();

   }
   }
```

**this is parseJsonResponse**

```
public void parseJsonResponse(String result) {

String res = result;
    if (res !=null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jObjects = new JSONObject(result);
            JAS = jObjects.getJSONArray("Data");
            for (int i = 0; i < JAS.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = JAS.getJSONObject(i);
                DetailedAddressInfo productinfo = new DetailedAddressInfo();
                productinfo.setFirstname(c.optString("firstname"));
                productinfo.setLastname(c.optString("lastname"));
                productinfo.setStreet(c.optString("street"));
                productinfo.setCity(c.optString("city"));
                productinfo.setRegion(c.optString("region"));
                productinfo.setPostcode(c.optString("postcode"));
                productinfo.setTelephone(c.optString("telephone"));
                productinfo.setFax(c.optString("fax"));
                productinfo.setAddId(c.optString("customer_address_id"));
                productinfo.setBilling(c.optString("is_default_billing"));
                productinfo.setShipping(c.optString("is_default_shipping"));


                products.add(productinfo);
                if (i == JAS.length() - 1) {
                    Last_id = c.optString("product_id");
                }
            }
            adapter = new DetailedAddressAdapter(DetaildAddress.this, R.layout.deshbord_address, products);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(DetaildAddress.this)
        .setTitle("No Address Available")
                .setMessage("You Want to Add New Address")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(DetaildAddress.this,NewAddress.class);
                        String ok = "0";
                        intent.putExtra("ok", ok);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();
    } if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

**this is OnCreate where I call AsyncTask**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detaild_address);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.layout_stub);
    stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.content_detaild_address);
    View inflated = stub.inflate();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    String check = "0";
    String chEck;
    DBHandler db = new DBHandler(DetaildAddress.this);
    List<DBconnector> Contacts = db.getAllContacts();
    for (DBconnector cn : Contacts) {
        chEck = cn.getActive();
        if(chEck != null){
            if (chEck.equals("1")){
                check = chEck;
            }
        }
    }
    if (check.equals("1")) {
        List<DBconnector> contacts = db.getActiveData();

        for (DBconnector c : contacts) {
            Customer_id = c.getCustomer_id();
            //new CheckAddress().execute();
            boolean connected = false;
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                    connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                //we are connected to a network
                new InfoAccountsascyn(DetaildAddress.this,url_address,Customer_id).execute();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(DetaildAddress.this,"Internet Connection is not Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent=new Intent(DetaildAddress.this,HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                connected = false;
            }

        }

    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(DetaildAddress.this, "Please login First", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(DetaildAddress.this, UserLogin.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    myLastVisiblePos = gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    products = new ArrayList<DetailedAddressInfo>();
    //gridView.setAdapter(new DetailedAddressAdapter(DetaildAddress.this, R.layout.deshbord_address, products));

    TextView newaddress=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.newaddress);
    newaddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(DetaildAddress.this,NewAddress.class);
            String ok = "0";
            intent.putExtra("ok", ok);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think this is nothing to do with your AsyncTask. It looks quite okay to me. Paste your adapter where you're populating the data. You might not have cleared the dataset when you're reloading the list/grid. That's a common mistake though.

Comment: are you calling execute() multiple times on the same instance of InfoAccountsascyn?

Comment: please check it again

Comment: post the part of code from where you are calling this asynctask

Comment: check It again part of code from where im calling this asynctask

Comment: @NKmewara did u find a solution???

Comment: yes @RakeshYadav

Comment: @RakeshYadav sometimes i don't know why data is repeated. because we call the request one's so i found the solution is before inserting the data in your array list check the size of array list if size is more the zero clear it like PRIYA PARASHAR's answer here is products is my array list

Comment: @NKmewara, after hitting my head again and again, it found the problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use clear() method of Arraylist before intialising the JSONObject like this:

```
if(products.size()>0)
 products.clear();
```

Comment: Because you create the object of arraylist once but you add same data again and again thats why it needs to clear the arraylist .

Comment: i have 4 address ok.. it load 4 address and again load same 4 address... problem is that AsyncTask onPostExecute method Call again automatically onPostExecute method run twicely..that is the problem...

Comment: and one thing if i call Adapter.clear() before set the adapter in gridview..address is not showing twice but this is not perfect solution..

Comment: Why your doInBackground and postExecute are not over rided from AsyncTask??

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I found a small problem in my code that **I was not dismissing the dialog** which I opened in onPostExecute() of my AsyncTask to do some extra work after AsyncTask Work.

When I called `myCustomDialog.dismiss()` everything worked fine.